# Vancouver with biblatex french format

Tags: biblatex

Even if I am using `\usepackage[french]{babel}` I don't have my information into French

`A partir de : [url...]` and like `. Récupérée le : 29 Septembre 2022`. (look at the first reference).

For the second reference i get `2013 feb` => I want `Février 2013.` (look at reference 2).

The illustration to understand the situation :
[image]

For a second time I want to know how can I get for reférence `[1]` : `Récupérée le 29 septembre 2022. A partir de https... a.`  basically I want to change the order of how elements are written

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@online{ministerium,
    author = {{Bundesministerium für Familie, Senioren, Frauen und Jugend}},
    title  = {{Stief- und Patchworkfamilien in Deutschland}},
    url    = {https://www.bmfsfj.de/resource/blob/76242/1ab4cc12c386789b943fc7e12fdef6a1/monitor-familienforschung-ausgabe-31-data.pdf},
    year   = {2013},
    urldate = {2022-09-29},
    
}
 @online{essai1,
    author = {Pibasso, Achille Mbog},
   year =   {2021},
    title = {Le Cameroun s’imprègne du modèle de la microfinance allemande},
   urldate = {2022-09-29},
   month =  {2021-01-22},
    url =   {https://www.financialafrik.com/2021/01/22/le-cameroun-sempreigne-du-modele-de-la-microfinance-allemande/}
 }



\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=vancouver,sorting=none,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{labelnumberwidth}{[#1]}
%option 1:
%\usepackage{xurl} % <-- important
%\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional
   

%option 2    
% formatting of hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}



\begin{document}
%\nocite{*}

\cite{essai1} et \cite{ministerium}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: For future questions please ask only about one issue per question. That makes it easier to answer your question. It's no problem to ask several questions. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason `biblatex-vancouver` does not make use of `biblatex`'s localisation feature and instead hard-codes English strings into the style.

We can try to roll that back as follows and return to the relevant bibstrings that would be used by standard `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=vancouver, citestyle=numeric, sorting=none, dateabbrev=false]{biblatex} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{#1}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
  urlseen = {récupérée le},
  urlfrom = {a partir de},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{urldate}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{url}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{ministerium,
  author  = {{Bundesministerium für Familie, Senioren, Frauen und Jugend}},
  title   = {{Stief- und Patchworkfamilien in Deutschland}},
  url     = {https://www.bmfsfj.de/resource/blob/76242/1ab4cc12c386789b943fc7e12fdef6a1/monitor-familienforschung-ausgabe-31-data.pdf},
  date    = {2013-02},
  urldate = {2022-09-29}, 
}
@online{essai1,
  author  = {Pibasso, Achille Mbog},
  title   = {Le Cameroun s’imprègne du modèle de la microfinance allemande},
  urldate = {2022-09-29},
  date    = {2021-01-22},
  url     = {https://www.financialafrik.com/2021/01/22/le-cameroun-sempreigne-du-modele-de-la-microfinance-allemande/},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{essai1} et \cite{ministerium}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bundesministerium für Familie, Senioren, Frauen und Jugend. Stief- und Patchworkfamilien in Deutschland. Février 2013. Récupérée le 29/09/2022. A partir de : https://www.bmfsfj.de/resource/blob/76242/1ab4cc12c386789b943fc7e12fdef6a1/monitor-familienforschung-ausgabe-31-data.pdf]

Comment: How to add [Récupérée le 29/09/2022] and also the command to have [Récupérée le 29 september 2022]

Comment: @Johnvador So just to be clear: Do you want the square brackets around the "Récupérée le ..."? What about the punctuation before and after? "2013. [Récupérée le 29 september 2022] A partir de : " or "2013. [Récupérée le 29 september 2022]. A partir de : " or ""2013 [Récupérée le 29 september 2022] A partir de : "? And what about the date format? Do you want 29/09/2022 or 29 september 2022?

Comment: I want to have both date format (have both command) =>  `22 janvier 2021. [Récupérée le 29 septembre 2022]. A partir de : https:...allemand/.` and   `22 janvier 2021. [Récupérée le 29/09/2022]. A partir de : https:...allemand/.`

Comment: @Johnvador Do you mean that you want to know how you can have each format? Or do you mean that you want both formats in the same document?

Comment: In the first case, you might want to check out the option `urldate=long,` (the default that you see at the moment is `urldate=short,`).

Comment: Yes I want to know how to do it in two different documents. ` 22 janvier 2021. [Récupérée le 29 septembre 2022]. A partir de : https:...allemand/.` and `22 janvier 2021. [Récupérée le 29/09/2022]. A partir de : https:...allemand/.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140156/discussion-between-johnvador-and-moewe).